# Multiple use of the same alt tag in multiple places on the blog

Tags: seo, images, alt-attribute

I have a blog on which I present all sorts of interesting design for different types of materials (flyers, business cards, document templates, etc.). I present both interesting examples of other creators, but also my own (there are a certain number of them and they appear in many articles on my blog).

And I wonder if I can add the same descriptive alt tag to all of them, clearly discussing what is in the image. In general, it will be the case that the same alt text will appear on my blog a dozen or more times, because it will refer to an image that just appears there repeatedly. The rest of the images will have different alts.

For example - one example of a business card I designed appears in 23 posts on my blog. And in each of the 23 entries would be the same alt tag.

Can the same alt repeatedly duplicated hurt my site?

Comment: I don't know if repeated use will "hurt" your site. But the alt tag is to help the vision-impaired to know what the picture is about. Every little extra bit of detail might help.

Comment: Perhaps this will help: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/125928/can-alt-text-be-the-same-for-multiple-product-images?rq=1

Comment: One expects that each image to have its own ALT text. If you use that image in several places on your website, the same ALT text should be present as well. Doesn't count as a duplicate, it's the expected behavior. What you shouldn't do is show a DIFFERENT alt text for the same image, as that can be seen as you are trying to manipulate the SERPs.